# How to make full back up of iPhone?

Tags: itunes, backup, restore

With iTunes popupmenu

[image]

I have just restored my iPhone from a backup from March 2012. However all my apps made with Xcode was sadly not restored.

How can I back up *everything*?

Besides Xcode apps, which other things does iTunes backup *not backup*?

Answer (score 2):

You don't get a backup of developer builds that are not ad-hoc builds (and thus synchronized with iTunes).

You also don't get backups of music, movies, podcasts. If you set the iPhone to be manually managed by you, you have to add all media back yourself. (Except ringtones and your photos)
I don't know, whether iTunes will resynchronize your media if you don't manually manage it.

Comment: immediately after a restore, iTunes performs a sync, which puts back all of your media using the same settings as before.

Comment: Like I said "If you set the iPhone to be manually managed by you, you have to add all media back yourself."   If you manually manage your media, then not even music and videos will automatically be synchronized back.

Comment: you also said " I don't know, whether iTunes will resynchronize your media if you don't manually manage it." I responded to that, confirming that yes it will indeed do that. I also said "the same settings as before", which implies that nothing will happen for manually managed media.

Comment: You are right, sorry. Didn't come over clearly enough to me that you were referring to the last part of my answer.